# Specify colours in geompoint for variable - ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am using ggplot with ggmap and following is the command I am using,

```
print(ggmap(m) + 
        geom_point(aes(x=ga_long, y=ga_lat, color = variable1, size = size) , data=il) + 
        scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,5)) + 
        xlab("Latitude") + ylab("Longitude") 
      # + scale_colour_continuous( c("green", "black", "red"))
)
```

Here for the color, I have given variable1. It seems to work fine, but I want to specify the colours as I am not comfortable with the already present colours. If there are three factors in the variable1, I would like to give green, black, red as combinations for specific factors. I've tried the following,

```
   print(ggmap(m) + 
            geom_point(aes(x=ga_long, y=ga_lat, color = 
                             ifelse(variable1 == 0, 'green', 
                                    ifelse(variable1 == 1, 'black', 'red')), size = size),  data=il) + 
            scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,5)) + 
            xlab("Latitude") + ylab("Longitude") 
          # + scale_colour_continuous( c("green", "black", "red"))
    )
```

But this one didn't help.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: use our first code with `scale_colour_manual` and set the values to your colours

Comment: @RichardTelford I tried this, scale_colour_manual( c("green", "black", "red"), I am getting, Error in f(...) : argument "values" is missing, with no default. Not sure what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: set the `values  = c("green", "black", "red")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close.  Try:

```
print(ggmap(m) + 
        geom_point(aes(x=ga_long, y=ga_lat, color = variable1, size = size) , data=il) + 
        scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,5)) + 
        xlab("Latitude") + ylab("Longitude") +
        scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "black", "red"))
)
```